# Ext JS UX - RowPanelExpander

Tags: extjs, grid, expander

I have this [plugin](http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?92994-RowPanelExpander-for-grids&highlight=RowPanelExpander). It works great with gridPanel. But there are some problems with editorGridPanel. After editing of some row plugin stops work. Maybe  someone can fix this problem? I looked at code, but cant find answer....

Comment: Have You debugged in FireBug?

Answer (score 0):

You really should contact the plugin author directly and/or ask in the Ext JS [ux/plugins forum](http://www.extjs.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?42-Ext-User-Extensions-and-Plugins).  Probably won't get an answer on SO...

Answer (score 0):

Looking shortly at the plugin code, I can see that row expander strongly relays on CSS classes for expand/collapse.

Maybe after grid editing row expander class is changed to unknown CSS class for plugin. 
Try to set CSS class to one of `x-grid3-row-collapsed`, `x-grid3-row-expanded` after editing.